# Using Flex Prana

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, inversion-of-control

How many of you already used the Prana Framework for AS3 (Flex/Flash) or heard about it?

I have found it very useful but there doesn't seem to be a lot of developers using it...

The link is [PranaFramework](http://www.pranaframework.org)

Comment: Despite the fact that the first sentence has a question mark at the end, it is not a question. There is no question anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Marcel Panse spoke about Prana at the JFall conference last wednesday in Bussum, the Netherlands. He states that it is one of the best "Spring like" frameworks for Flex. I'm no Flex developer but I could see the resemblance with Spring.

His slides are here:
http://www.slideshare.net/marcel.panse/flex-in-de-praktijk-presentation/

(Sorry, most of it is in Dutch)